# Will I be able to mine having my whole blockchain imported using the "light" syncmode?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, synchronization

I was having trouble with "fast" method and opted for this mode.  It seems to have worked in actually syncing up the blockchain.  As I understand at this point it only downloads the current "state" of the block chain, not the historical receipts of each block.  **In short will I be able to start mining with genoils now that this is downloaded?**  I'm fine if it causes further workload down the line for the actual hashrate as long as I get to the next step.